# Equivalent size html element to normalize title spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I have an html element which is present on some elements, but not others. For the ones which it is not present, I need to have a size-equivalent empty space html element. This ensures that the spacing is not off.

I have tried adding the same element, but putting `hidden`, `hidden="hidden"` and `style="visibility:hidden;"` on the div that encapsulats the element, but that makes the build fail. Any thoughts?

Comment: "makes the build fail" Is there an error?

Comment: Could you give us more detail, it seems that you could easily solve this with CSS by either using the :empty pseudo-selector or the + selector, you could even just use flexbox, and set a flex-basis, maybe even display: grid might solve it.

Comment: Please show us enough. Code for us to see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `opacity: 0` instead of visibility.

Comment: What the OP tried should work, but all we know is that they "[make] the build fail." We need to know why those aren't working before throwing more potential solutions at it, as `visibility: hidden` is the "correct" method for this.